Why is the version of a bitcoin transaction is 4 bytes?
Here is a raw bitcoin transaction. I wonder what was the reasoning to make it 4 bytes rather than 1 byte(256 possible version numbers) or 2 bytes(65536 possible version numbers)?


As with many design decisions for the original Bitcoin protocol, the answer is simply "because it seemed like a good idea to Satoshi". The raw transaction format includes both variable-length numbers (called "CompactSize", used for input and output counts and script sizes) and fixed-length numbers, both 4-byte (version, sequence, prevout index, locktime) and 8-byte (output amount), so in this sense the version field doesn't really stand out. Also note blocks too have a 4-byte version field.

Only Satoshi Nakamoto knows the right answer :)

Bitcoin's transaction version is 4 bytes to accommodate flexibility and make it future-proof. Indeed, this allows for diverse types of transactions as the protocol evolves. With 4 bytes or 32 bits, the number of available version numbers is over 4.29 billion in comparison with 1 byte, which has 256 possibilities, or 2 bytes, with 65,536 possibilities. Of course, this many bytes would be more than enough for future updates, as well as for something as complex as the one introduced by SegWit. Another reason for this choice is that most programming languages process data in 4-byte blocks, so this is efficient and minimizes memory alignment issues. In general, using 4 bytes keeps consistency with the protocol and fits with other fields like timestamp and block version.
